# wordpress get_the_terms not work

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my query to show my work in the portfolio

```
<?php

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=> 'portfolio' ) );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
            $medium = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
            $url_thumb = $thumb['0'];
            $url_medium = $medium['0'];

            $option = '<li>';
            $option .= '<a data-value="' . get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio' ) . '" data-largesrc="' . $url_medium .'" data-title="' . get_the_title() .'" data-description="' . get_the_content() .'">';
            $option .= '<img src="' . $url_thumb . '" alt="img01" />';
            $option .= '</a>';
            $option .= '</li>';
            echo $option;
        }
    } else {

    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

The problem is here, in the data-value I need to extract the category of work

```
data-value="' . get_the_terms( 'portfolio', $post->ID ) . '"
```

I think the code that I use is wrong because if I put online I truncates the code and I do not show anything

Answer (score 3):

Your code suggests that `portfolio` is a custom post type, not a custom taxonomy, but you are passing it as the taxonomy parameter for `get_the_terms()`.  These are not the same things - post types are types of content (e.g. posts, pages) and taxonomies are ways to organize and group things (e.g. tags, categories).

You need to pass the slug of the custom taxonomy as the `$taxonomy` parameter, not the slug of the custom post type `portfolio`.  I don't know what taxonomy you are querying but it is probably something like `portfolio_categories` or similar.  For example if you were using the default `category` taxonomy with the post you would want `get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');`

Comment: It is my custom content type called portfolio.
I created the categories on the inside to differentiate the work ...
I'm sorry I'm a web designer who understands little of code .... you would know more than simply help

Comment: How did you create the categories for portfolio posts? Some kind of plugin? As I said, you are probably using a custom taxonomy - you just need to figure out what its slug (programmatic name) is.  It's also possible you have it set up to use 'normal' categories.

Comment: I'll explain what I need to get ...
value in the data I need to extract what category my single post

I have my custom content type called portfolio
and five categories to differentiate my work

Comment: Right I understand that, what I am trying to establish is whether you assigned the default built-in `category` taxonomy (usually used for blog posts) to your `portfolio` post type, or if you created a new custom taxonomy for the portfolio categories. If `get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');` does not display anything, it means the latter case is true, in which case you need to figure out what the slug of the custom taxonomy for portfolio categories is (this will depend on the code, or plugin you used to generate the custom taxonomy and post type).

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong syntax, the right syntax is

```
     <?php get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy ); ?>
```